# C# dynamic casting during operator evaluation

Tags: c#

I currently have a user defined type

```
class MyType {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    //This class has operator overloading implemented
    public static MyType operator + (double a,MyType b){
        ...
    }
}
```

At some point later I will have an array (object[]) some of them double and some MyType. I would like to do evaluation over them but compiler is not allowing operator '+' to be applied to type object and object. What should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resolving a `+` in code the compiler needs to bind it to a specific operation.  The type `object` has no `+` operation and the compiler has no idea that the underlying types are `double` and `MyType` and hence the compiler errors out.

In order to fix this you will need to either

- statically convert the elements to `double` and `MyType` so the compiler can properly bind the `+` operator
- use `dynamic` and rely on the runtime binding to the correct `operator+`.

Here is an example of the latter method.

```
class MyType {
    double _value;

    internal MyType(double value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static MyType operator +(double left, MyType right) {
        return new MyType(left + right._value);
    }

    public static MyType operator +(MyType left, double right) {
        return new MyType(left._value + right);
    }

    public static MyType operator +(MyType left, MyType right) {
        return new MyType(left._value + right._value);
    }

    public static implicit operator MyType(double other) {
        return new MyType(other);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        object[] them = new object[] {
            42,
            new MyType(13),
            12,
            new MyType(12)
        };

        dynamic all = them;
        MyType sum = 0;
        foreach (dynamic element in all) {
            sum += element;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed however I am using 3.5 and dynamic is not availible.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would create a `MyType` constructor that took a single `double` parameter, and use that to convert each `double` to a `MyType`, so that you could just use a `MyType[]` (or `List<MyType>`).

I understand that's really not what you're asking, but you'd still be able to handle the `MyType` creation such that the addition will perform properly, and you'd be more type-safe with your array.

Comment: When doing mytype+double , each value in mytype get added with the double. Converting double to mytype loses that.

Comment: You can create a one-argument `MyType` constructor like this: `MyType(double a) { x = y = z = a; }`.

Comment: I'm assuming, of course, that adding together two `MyType` objects results in a new `MyType` where the x, y and z fields have been added together.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with your types - the reason you cannot add is because object could be anyting in the system.

Is there any way that you can change object for a more specific type?

If it absolutely has to be object then you will have to evaluate at run-time using casts or the as operator or some similar mechanism.

eg

```
    public static MyType operator +(object o, MyType b)
    {
        MyOtherType mot = o as MyOtherType;
        if(o!=null)
            ...
```

but be in no doubt that your solution here raises questions about your design choices